# Getting sequence from LINUX / SQL_LOADER

Tags: linux, sqlplus

I have a Linux batch that looks like this:

```
export ORACLE SID=prod
export ORACL_HOME=/usr/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/db_12201
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
batch_id = `sqlplus / <<QB
SELECT BATCH_ID_SEQ.NEXVAL FROM DUAL;
exit;
QB`
echo "$batch_id"
```

I get an error saying table not found.  I checked the Linux id does have select privileges on the sequence.

This query does work'

```
 batch_id = `sqlplus / <<QB
SELECT MAX(Batch_ID) FROM BATCHES;
exit;
QB`
echo "$batch_id"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was permissions.  My unix ID was scrpt and I granted access to the sequence to OPS$scrpt.  I needed to assign permissions to use scrpt.